# how to add loader when on the toggle button

Tags: flutter, switch-statement, toggle, loader

I want to display a circular loader when user is going to on the toggle button, then after few secs toggle button will active.

here is my code

```
InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => ProductProfile(),
                        ));
                      },
                      child: Container(
                         decoration: BoxDecoration(
                       color: _selectedProducts.contains(book.id) ? Colors.grey[200] :Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                       
                        child: ListTile(
                          dense: true,
                          trailing: Switch(
                            value: _selectedProducts.contains(book.id),
                            onChanged: (bool? selected) {
                              if (selected != null) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _onProductSelected(selected, book.id);
                                });
                              }
                            },
                            activeTrackColor: HexColor("#b8c2cc"),
                            activeColor: HexColor("#7367f0"),
                          ),
                          title: Text(
                            book.title,),
                              Divider()
                          
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox10(),
                  ],
                );
```

please help how to do this

Comment: You want the loader to appear when you hover over the `InkWell` ? Is this a web project ?

Comment: yes i want a loader a circular loader, but when i on a toggle button, no this mobile app, in flutter

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that, you need `bool _isLoading` and a `timer`. Steps I would do:

- Declare _isLoading: `bool _isLoading = false;`
- Change _isLoading value using a timer:

  ```
  void timer() {
    int _time = 10;

    Timer timer = new Timer.periodic(
      Duration(seconds: 1),
      (Timer timer) async {
        if (_time == 0) {
          _isLoading = true;
          timer.cancel();
        } else {
          setState(() {
            _time--;
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }
  ```
- Use _isLoading on your build method (for example):

  ```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _isLoading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Container();
  }
  ```
- Or to hide your button:

  ```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _isLoading ? Container() : YourToggleButton;
  }
  ```
- Also remember to dispose your timer!

  ```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer.cancel();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

So, If you are on Flutter web, there is a widget called `MouseRegion` which has `onHover`, `onEnter` & `onExit`.

You can assign a new `bool` for instance `bool showLoader=false` which you will toggle to true with `setState` (inside the `onHover`, where you could also start the `Timer` and when finished reset the `showLoader` to false).

Now you can show your button with a ternary operator : `showLoader ? CircularProgressIndicator() : YourButton()`